# XPath evaluation in dom4j Document created from org.w3c.dom.Document doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I'm trying to use dom4j 1.6.1 to traverse the following document using XPath. I'm looking for the number of `<query>` elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reportLineageResponse>
   <querySet expressionLocale="en-us">
      <queries xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/9.0/">
         <query name="Top 10 Sales Staff List"/>
         <query name="Top 10 Sales Staff by Quantity List"/>
         <query name="Sales Figures America Region Combination Chart"/>
      </queries>
   </querySet>
</reportLineageResponse>
```

Here is the code invoking dom4j.

```
int numberOfQueries(org.w3c.dom.Document jaxpDocument) {
    DOMReader domReader = new DOMReader();
    org.dom4j.Document document = domReader.read(jaxpDocument);

    Map<String, String> nsMap = Collections.singletonMap("rep", "http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/9.0/");
    XPath queryXp = document.createXPath("/reportLineageResponse/querySet/rep:queries/rep:query")
    queryXp.setNamespaceURIs(nsMap);
    List<Node> queries = queryXp.selectNodes(document);
    return queries.size();
}
```

I specified the namespace correctly, yet I get 0 results. What could be the problem?

---

Edit: if I look at the dom4j.Document after creating it, it has the namespaces wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reportLineageResponse>
   <querySet expressionLocale="en-us">
      <queries xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/report/9.0/">
         <query xmlns="" name="Top 10 Sales Staff List"/>
         <query xmlns="" name="Top 10 Sales Staff by Quantity List"/>
         <query xmlns="" name="Sales Figures America Region Combination Chart"/>
      </queries>
   </querySet>
</reportLineageResponse>
```

---

Edit: here is the code that creates the org.w3c.dom.Document:

```
Document loadDocument(URL url) {
    InputStream stream = url.openStream();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document result = docBuilder.parse(stream);
    stream.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me, can you include the code which creates a `Document`?

Comment: @dusan I've included the code.

Comment: How are you creating `org.w3c.dom.Document jaxpDocument`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your xml loading as follows:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactor = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
docBuilderFactor.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
```